# Getting the current time and date in the device's defined format

Tags: android, date

How can I get the current time and date according to phone device format?

**my code is**

```
Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",
Locale.ENGLISH);

String var = dateFormat.format(date));
```

It displays like 2PM instead of 14PM.

Comment: hh:mm aa change to HH

Comment: @GeorgeThomas - this is a fix for the specific scenario in the example, which is __wrong__ in the case that the device's format is `hh`.

Comment: @Dev-iL - then i think we will have to check using DateFormat.is24HourFormat(context)
and apply correspondingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can the device format data and time using

```
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
    Log.d(TAG,dateFormat.format(date)+");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar object instead of Date because it is deprecated now and by using caledar object you can get hour in 12 hours formate  [as](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR)

```
int hour = calendarObject.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

for 24 formate [as](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#HOUR_OF_DAY):

```
int hour = calendarObject.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

for further detail you can visit [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html)

Answer (score -1):

Just change "hh:mm aa" to "HH:mm aa"